# SocketTimeout Exception When calling a webservice

Tags: android, socket-timeout-exception

I am using a webservice in my application using android v4.0.3, but when i reached at
`HttpTransportse` Shows `SocketTimeoutException` and not getting response.The same code working perfectly in android.v.2.2

I got the following Exception  in logcat

```
05-10 11:18:38.245: W/System.err(849): java.net.SocketTimeoutException
05-10 11:18:38.255: W/System.err(849):  at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:130)

KSoap jar
---------
KSoap2 library android:2.5.2.jar
```

here is the code

```
public class busTravellDetailslistActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
Button b;
EditText rteid,trvname,bustyp,deptm,arvtm;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    b=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            SoapObject request = new SoapObject("http://***********/WS2","TestRouteDataMobile");
                //System.out.println("req count:"+request.getPropertyCount()); 
            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope=new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

              envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

              HttpTransportSE transport = new HttpTransportSE("http://**********/RouteSearchService.asmx");//namespace
                try {

                    transport.call("http://***********/TestRouteDataMobile",envelope);
                    System.out.println("aftr call");
                } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                    SoapObject response;
                    try {
                        response = (SoapObject)(envelope.getResponse());

                        Log.i("Response",response.toString());




                    } catch (SoapFault e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
    });
    }
}
```

Comment: ok got it , I had same problem, Just you need to clean the variables after response.

Comment: I got answer  when i run from the project and there itself asking in which emulutor have to run.But when i made change the emulator from properties and androidmanifest,the same exception showing..why it is happening like this??or is any problem what i had done??

Comment: did you build and clean after changes ?

Comment: I did the same,but still have..

Comment: need a solution frm anybody else..

Comment: can you please upload the code , after the changes you made

Answer (score 0):

I spent almost 2-3 hours to fix this problem and the solution was very easy. This problem comes when either you are accessing web service at wrong IP or Service has some problems. But except these two there is one thing you need to be caution which is if web service is hosted at Http then you should use `HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);` and if your web service is at https, then use `HttpsTransportSE aht = new KeepAliveHttpsTransportSE(IP, 443,SERVICEPATH, 25000);`. I hope would help you.